# SignalR stop working when there are no connections to it

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

i tried to ask in theASP.net signalR tutorial but they couldn't resolve my issue.
i followed the following tutorial http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20
completed it and for some reason every time no one connected to the site, the application stopped working although it should work all the time also when clients are not connected to it.
be advised that it stopped working in the server 20 minutes after the last client disconnected(don't see the W3WP app in the task manager in the server)

any idea why it happens?
is it supposed to happen with this technology?

Comment: Iis session default timeout is 20 mins. Check if something is wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shutting down of worker process after 20 minutes of inactivity is the default behaviour of IIS `Application Pool`. You can set `Idle Time-out` to 0 in the advanced settings of the `Application Pool`.

Answer (score 2):

There must be some underlying issue with the application, as SignalR is just a communication mechanism between server and client.
The SignalR server will send messages to any connected clients when it is told to do so - generally when some event occurs server side.  If there are no clients - this will NOT cause SignalR to stop.  As long as the SignalR server process is running, it will continue to allow new client connections - no matter how long between connections.

Comment: any way the reason relies on the IIS version/settings?